# Retroactive reputation changes

Tags: feature-request, reputation, downvotes

Take a look at [this user’s reputation points changes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3688755/djbhindi?tab=reputation). As I write this, it's at 6. He got 2 question downvotes, then one upvote. (IMO the upvote was undeserved, as I was one of the downvoters.) Had it been the other way around, he would only have 4. But because reputation points can’t dip below 0, the downvotes didn't affect him.

Can we get retroactive reputation points losses for cases like these?

Comment: If your intention is to hurt the person, don't bother. Anyone running into this often is likely to be banned anyway.

Comment: @Mysticial not to hurt the person necessarily, but so that the upvotes don't give them quite as much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not asking for reputation to be retroactive.  There was no change to the rules of calculating reputation that should affect the existing reputation totals.

What you're asking for is reputation to be allowed to be negative (even if we lie and display a "1", what you're asking for is for the "real" reputation to functionally go negative).

This concept has been specifically rejected.  Reputation won't ever go below 1.